# GCC errors on Aarch64 (RK3568 SoC board) from Buildroot

Tags: c, gcc, arm64, buildroot

I have loaded GCC (11.4.0) onto a custom Buildroot distribution (kernel 4.19), and am unable to compile an intro "hello.c" (hello world) program due to ranlib and header errors.

```
# gcc -g -ansi -pedantic -Wall hello.c -o hello
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-buildroot-linux-
gnu/11.3.0/../../../../aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/bin/ld: 
/usr/lib64/libc_nonshared.a: error adding symbols: archive has 
no index; run ranlib to add one
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I compile to an object file using `gcc -c -g -ansi -pedantic -Wall hello.c -o hello.o` it compiles, and the `file` output reads:
`hello.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), with debug_info, not stripped` which indicates I am compiling for the correct platform.

If I try to apply the `ranlib` tool the indicated missing library, I then get the following error when rebuilding:

```
# ranlib /usr/lib64/libc_nonshared.a
# gcc -g -ansi -pedantic -Wall hello.c -o hello
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-buildroot-linux
gnu/11.3.0/../../../../aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/bin/ld: 
error in /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-buildroot-linux-
gnu/11.3.0/../../../../lib64/crt1.o(.eh_frame); no 
.eh_frame_hdr table will be created
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/11.3.0/../../../../aarch64- 
buildroot-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; 
defaulting to 0000000000400440
```

From my (limited) understanding, the `crt1.o(.eh_frame); no  .eh_frame_hdr table will be created` may be related to having multiple definitions -- including the same files twice (though I'm not sure) and I'd love some hints as to what to try as I am quite new to compilers and linkers.

**EDIT 1:** My cross-compilation environment is WSL2 running on Windows 11, and `gcc` builds hello.o with the following `file` characteristics:

```
hello.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), with debug_info, not stripped
```

Comment: Are you cross-compiling, or compiling in the native environment? If cross-compiling, running `gcc` seem to be wrong

Comment: I'm cross-compiling! It's not a good idea in prod. or deployment but as a case study was curious to see if I could get it to work

Comment: So you are running `gcc`, which doesn't seem to be a cross-compiler for your target. I would expect to see something like `gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu` instead.

Comment: I am cross-compiling in Windows 11 on WSL2,I've posted the arch for compiled files above. Do you mean that I should see gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu on my target, because the target GCC is running natively and so it makes sense to have ARM Aarch64 arch

Comment: You are using an x86 machine to compile on, while the target architecture is Aarch64. Cross-compiling means that you need a compiler that *runs* on x86, but producing binaries for Aarch64. Such compilers usually have the suffix indicating the target architecture/ABI similar to `gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu` or `gcc-aarch64-none-gnueabi` and such. When you use `gcc` you are likely compiling for the same target as your environment (that is x86)

Comment: That does not seem consistent with the output of the file command? It shows that hello.o was compiled for ARM Aarch64

Comment: If with "custom Buildroot distribution" you mean "an image built with https://buildroot.org", then compilation on the target is not going to work. You need to adapt your Buildroot configuration to build whatever you need and add it to the target.

Comment: yes I mean an image built using Buildroot. I don't see why compilation *should not* work, this is an experiment to get the compiler working on target -- the compiler should be able to be built by the cross-compilation toolchain.